# Line-by-line Shell

Tags: bash, shell, sh

i'm trying to write a shell script that performs a few commands in a row. However, when I do

```
VAR_1=/usr/home/cake/
##perform long task
ls $VAR_1
rm -rf ${VAR_1}file.tgz
ls $VAR_1
```

It removes the file but does not list the directory for the 2nd time. I'm unsure why.

Comment: Is there a newline after the last line in the script?

Comment: @choroba Yes. Tried both, though

Comment: For me it works good :)

Comment: @MortezaLSC Nice. For me it doesn't :)

Comment: The ##perform long task is tar an entire directory if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the script as `bash -x script.sh`. This will print the lines as it executes them. This way you should see what command are executed and where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few recommendations:

- You can always echo line in your shell script to see what's going on.
- You can also use `set -xv` to help you debug a shell script. Simply put `set -xv` before the part you want to debug, and `set +xv` to turn off the debug. You can also use `export PS4="\$LINENO> "` to print out the line number in your shell script.

Try to debug it.